# Recorrido de Array en Python flask

Tags: python, array, flask

Hola estoy programando en python flask. Pero tengo que hacer un recorrido para agregar datos en una parte de mi diccionario pero si coloco un append me da el siguiente error ERROR : 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'.
Mi código es el siguiente.

```
@app.route('/docs', methods=['POST'])
def create_document():
   try:
        new_doc = request.get_json()

        name = new_doc['name']
        label = new_doc['label']
        id = new_doc['id']
        name_items = new_doc['name_items']
        label_items = new_doc['label_items']
        type_items = new_doc['type_items']

        new_document = {
            "name": name,
            "label": label,
            "owner": {
                "id": id
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": name_items,
                    "label": label_items,
                    "type": type_items
                }
            ]
        }
        print(new_document)

        new_items = new_document["items"][0]

        for i in new_items:
          new_items.append(i)
          print(new_items)

        return jsonify({'mensaje': "Documento registrado"})
    except Exception as ex:
        print("ERROR : " + str(ex))
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué es lo que quieres agregar a tu diccionario? En la línea `new_items = new_document["items"][0]` estás accediendo directamente al diccionario y los diccionarios no tienen `append` ¿O quieres agregar un nuevo diccionario a tu lista de `items`?

Comment: has probado la function update?

Comment: Exacto quiero agregar un nuevo diccionario a la lista items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema que tienes en tu código es que estas intentando utilizar `append()` en un elemento de tu diccionario `new_document["items"][0]` y los diccionarios no tienen append, tendrías que hacerlo en `new_document["items"]`

Tendrías que crear una lista de diccionarios con todos los elementos que quieras agregar a `items` por ejemplo:

```
#new_items es una lista de diccionarios
new_items = [               #Esto es una lista
    {                       #Esto es un diccionario
        'name': 'name_items_1',
        'label': 'labell_items_1',
        'type': 'type_items_1'
    },
    {                       #Esto es un diccionario
        'name': 'name_items_2',
        'label': 'labell_items_2',
        'type': 'type_items_2'
    },
    {                       #Esto es un diccionario
        'name': 'name_items_3',
        'label': 'labell_items_3',
        'type': 'type_items_3'
    }
]
```

Luego vas a agregar esa lista de diccionarios a tu `new_document["items"]`

```
for item in new_items:
  new_document['items'].append(item)
```

Aquí está el ejemplo completo funcionando

```
new_document = {
  'name': 'name',
  'label': 'label',
  'owner': {
    'id': 'id'
  },
  'items': [
    {
      'name': 'name_items',
      'label': 'label_items',
      'type': 'type_items'
    }
  ]
}

#new_items es una lista de diccionarios
new_items = [               #Esto es una lista
    {                       #Esto es un diccionario
        'name': 'name_items_1',
        'label': 'labell_items_1',
        'type': 'type_items_1'
    },
    {                       #Esto es un diccionario
        'name': 'name_items_2',
        'label': 'labell_items_2',
        'type': 'type_items_2'
    },
    {                       #Esto es un diccionario
        'name': 'name_items_3',
        'label': 'labell_items_3',
        'type': 'type_items_3'
    }
]

print('Antes:')
print(new_document)

for item in new_items:
  new_document['items'].append(item)

print('Después:')
print(new_document)
```

Y la salida de ese código es:

```
Antes:
{
    'name': 'name',
    'label': 'label',
    'owner': 
    {
        'id': 'id'
    },
    'items': 
    [
        {
             'name': 'name_items',
             'label': 'label_items',
             'type': 'type_items'
        }
    ]
}

Después:
{
    'name': 'name', 
    'label': 'label', 
    'owner': 
    {
        'id': 'id'
    }, 
    'items': 
    [
        {
            'name': 'name_items', 
            'label': 'label_items', 
            'type': 'type_items'
        }, 
        {
            'name': 'name_items_1', 
            'label': 'labell_items_1', 
            'type': 'type_items_1'
        }, 
        {
            'name': 'name_items_2', 
            'label': 'labell_items_2', 
            'type': 'type_items_2'
        }, 
        {
            'name': 'name_items_3', 
            'label': 'labell_items_3', 
            'type': 'type_items_3'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ahorita cambie un poco el código pero sigue siendo relativamente lo mismo.

Comment: Pero con lo que me comentaste me esta dando este error ERROR : list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: De echo los valores items los estoy mandando desde postman asi [
    {
        "name_items": "fecha",
        "label_items": "Fecha de inicio",
        "type_items": "date"
    },
    {
        "name_items": "folio",
        "label_items": "Folio certificado",
        "type_items": "text"
    }
]

Comment: ¿Puedes crear una nueva pregunta con el nuevo código que tienes y la descripción del problema? Lo que creo que puede estar pasando es que estás asignando llaves a una lista. Pon el link para tu otra pregunta aquí para que pueda saber cuando la hagas. Saludos

Comment: Esta abajo como una respuesta. Espero me puedas apoyar el view_items sigue siendo un lista pero ahora esta vacia. Si mando de echo un valor solo en postam parecido a este {
        "name_items": "fecha",
        "label_items": "Fecha de inicio",
        "type_items": "date"
    }                                                                                                                                       No hay problema pero si mando algo como la respuesta anterior me da ese problema

Comment: No se pueden publicar nuevas preguntas como respuestas, esa sección va a ser eliminada por la comunidad. voy a empezar a revisarlo pero por favor crea una nueva pregunta

Comment: Ya vi el problema, `new_items` no es una lista, es lo que te comenté en la respuesta, sigues utilizando un diccionario y lo que necesitas es una lista de diccionarios (Te hacen falta los corchetes `[ ]` )

Comment: Ya realice la otra pregunta esta mas completa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/517073/error-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str