# ERROR : list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, flask

Tengo problemas con el siguiente codigo me da el error mostrado en el titulo. Me pueden ayudar.

```
@app.route('/docs', methods=['POST'])
def create_document():
    try:
        new_doc = request.get_json()

        new_document = {
            "name": new_doc['name'],
            "label": new_doc['label'],
            "owner": {
                "id":  new_doc['id']
            },
            "items": []
        }
        print(new_document)

        mydata["documents"].append(new_document)

        return jsonify(new_document)

    except Exception as ex:
        print("MISTAKE: " + str(ex))

@app.route('/docs/<string:name>/items', methods=['POST'])
def create_items(name):
    try:
        for doc in mydata["documents"]:
            entityName = doc["name"]
            if entityName == name:

                view_items = doc["items"]

                req_data = request.get_json()
                new_items = {
                    "name_items": req_data['name_items'],
                    "label_items": req_data['label_items'],
                    "type_items": req_data['type_items']
                }

                view_items.append(new_items)

                print(view_items)

                for item in new_items:
                    view_items.append(item)
                    print(view_items)

                return jsonify(new_items)
        return jsonify({'message': 'Document invalid'})

    except Exception as ex:
        print("ERROR : " + str(ex))
```

Comment: Buen día, gracias por crear la nueva pregunta. Cuando haces `view_items.append(new_items)` y luego `print(view_items)` puedes ver que los nuevos elementos se agregaron a `view_items `?

Comment: Si, por que de echo ahi si veo la respuesta y en postman mando esto     {"name_items": "fecha",
        "label_items": "Fecha de inicio",
        "type_items": "date"
    }                                                                                                                                   y como respuesta obtengo esto: [{'name_items': 'fecha', 'label_items': 'Fecha de inicio', 'type_items': 'date'}] y mi print despues de for me da esto: [{'name_items': 'fecha', 'label_items': 'Fecha de inicio', 'type_items': 'date'}, 'name_items', 'label_items', 'type_items']

Comment: Pero si en postman mando algo así [
    {
        "name_items": "fecha",
        "label_items": "Fecha de inicio",
        "type_items": "date"
    },
    {
        "name_items": "fecha",
        "label_items": "Fecha de inicio",
        "type_items": "date"
    }
] es cuando me da el error que esta en el titulo de la pregunta

Comment: Pero ¿Cuál es tu intención al usar el `for`? Parece que quieres agregar los valores a `view_items` pero eso ya lo haces con `view_items.append(new_items)` entonces no entiendo el motivo del `for`

Comment: Quiero agregar mas valores en view_items tomando en cuenta ese diccionario de new_items. Justo quiero algo así  [ { "name_items": "fecha", "label_items": "Fecha de inicio", "type_items": "date" }, { "name_items": "fecha", "label_items": "Fecha de inicio", "type_items": "date" } ] por  que todo o estoy mandando a través de POSTMAN

Comment: Para mas especifico quiero que si en postman mando algo asi  [ { "name_items": "fecha", "label_items": "Fecha de inicio", "type_items": "date" }, { "name_items": "fecha", "label_items": "Fecha de inicio", "type_items": "date" } ]  esto me lo almacene como un nuevo diccionario en view_items

Comment: Ok pero eso ya lo hace con `view_items.append(new_items)` aquí estas agregando todos los elementos de tu lista de diccionarios a `view_items`